# Using @DefaultValue with RESTEasy Client framework

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

Can we use the @defaultValue annotation when using the RESTEasy client framework ?

The compiler doesn't complain about this :

```
public interface XClient {  

@GET
@Path("/rest/search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)    
public String getInformation(
        @QueryParam("partner") @DefaultValue("xxxxxx") String apiKey);
}
```

But how can I call this getInformation method without passing the apiKey parameter. In a way that the "xxxxxx" value would be taken instead.

Is that possible or am I misunderstanding the @DefaultValue annotation purpose ?

**EDIT :**

This cannot be done using the @DefaultValue annotation. Maybe there is another solution. There is not much documentation about the client side of the RESTEasy framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot be done using the @DefaultValue annotation (Using the Client Framework).

Answer (score 0):

`@DefaultValue` is a parameter annotation that can be combined with any other `@*Param` annotations to define a default value where the HTTP request item does not exist.

See [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html-single/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/index.html#_DefaultValue)

So it is possible.

Comment: Please see my comment in the Aure77 answer.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultValue is used if QueryParam is not set in the url :

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html

*http://localhost/rest/search*  -> default value used as apiKey

*http://localhost/rest/search?partner=1*  -> "1" is used as apiKey

Comment: I'm using the client side of the framework. (Using to call some third party Rest WS). That's why XClient is an interface, not a class. So the question remains, is it possible to use in the client framework ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't see that is client side !
Do you try sending a *null* param to the method (to get the default value) ?

Comment: It was the first thing I've tried. Passing null during the call doesn't get the @defaultvalue value. It just passes null to the invoke method. I think this annotation only work for the server side.

Comment: I think too. It's not possible in Java to not passing an argument when a method requiered one... Only server side because handling HTTP request